# Getting specific value after a findall

Tags: python

I have the following code which gathers a list of devices connected to a computer it returns a UDID: and then serial number so a correct return looks like this

[UDID: 340ad1234dfawd123, UDID: 123ads345ads45112]

My current code is returning these correctly however I need it to give me just the serial numbers so I can loop from one serial number to the next so they can be tested one by one.

My current code looks like this:

```
def list_devices():
    out = subprocess.getoutput([GBTest, '--list-devices'])
    DEVICES = [out]
    UDID = out.split(' : ')[-1]
    #return UDID
    items=re.findall("UDID: *.*",UDID,re.MULTILINE)
    return items
```

How can I add a line that will pull be just the serial numbers so I can run from one to the next?

Thank you very much for the help with a new user!

Here is a sample value for out

Name: SM-900 | UDID: 1234adawdawd1231244adaw

Name: phone | UDID: 7891263ajbd092173

Comment: just to be certain, can you provide a sample value for `out`. Also, the serial number is the second `UDID` value? please put the sample value in the OP with an edit, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Added sample for out

Comment: as mentioned  by shawn please provide the sample value for `out` and correct code` which ll help us to understand the problem clearly

Comment: ok, thx @user1304228. So you have given us two valid input values. Now, please, for each of those indicate what a *correct* output would be. =+1 for TDD :)

Comment: What is the type of the return value in `out`? is it a `str`? If there are multiple entries (e.g., SM-900 and phone in the one return) what separates them?

Comment: Pretty sure these are coming out as a list, since when I tried to run a items.split on them I got an Attribute Error list object has no attribute for split

Comment: As for the correct output of out, it is correct...  I just need a way to grab that serial number that appears after UDID:

Comment: so you just want the str that appears after `UDID` in each line of out?

Comment: ya that is all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here are a couple of methods:

Firstly, here is my **test input**

```
input = ['Name: SM-900 | UDID: 1234adawdawd1231244adaw',
         'Name: phone | UDID: 7891263ajbd092173']
```

Here is a method that works with that input list.

```
def new_list_devices(devices):
    serial_numbers = [] # init an empty list to store results
    for entry in devices: # create a loop for each device listed
        serial_numbers.append(entry.split(': ')[-1]) # append the split value
    return serial_numbers # return it
```

which you can test with

```
print(new_list_devices(input))
```

and it outputs for me:

> ['1234adawdawd1231244adaw', '7891263ajbd092173']

Now to improve:

```
def better_new_list_devices(devices):
    return [entry.split(': ')[-1] for entry in devices]


print(better_new_list_devices(input))
```

which yields the same output.

The better method uses a **list comprehension** to build the list in place and return it directly.

The only thing then that you need to adapt is to determine how to get the input into the method. You could

```
def better_new_list_devices():
    return [entry.split(': ')[-1] for entry in subprocess.getoutput([GBTest, '--list-devices']]
```

or if that is too much break it out

```
def better_new_list_devices():
    devices = subprocess.getoutput([GBTest, '--list-devices']
    return [entry.split(': ')[-1] for entry in devices]
```

or you could even pass your input list as the argument, so

```
def better_new_list_devices(devices):
    return [entry.split(': ')[-1] for entry in devices]
```

called with

```
better_new_list_devices(subprocess.getoutput([GBTest, '--list-devices'])
```

Comment: Thank you sir, took bits and pieces of that and got what I was after

Comment: good. just remember that 1) the standard string methods are very powerful and you should reach for them first before resorting to `re` - you had the correct split, but you were taking your list and putting in into another list, which leads to 2) think about the type of your object at each point in the code. I suspect that you were getting a list in `out` so you didn't need to `[out]` which is a list of a list. good luck